# How do I make a navigation bar "affix" itself to the top of the page when a user scrolls a certain amount?

Tags: html, css

I am new to this Bootstrap Affix. I am going to try to be as clear as possible when I ask this: I have this new website I am developing. In the header, I have a picture on top and then the navigation bar.

When a user scrolls a certain amount, I would like the picture to scroll off the top of the page and the navigation bar to become "fixed" to the top of the page. But, when the user scrolls back up the page, I would like the navigation bar to go back where it was and the picture to go back where it was.

I understand you have to use classes, but I don't know what classes I am supposed to use.

Some of you might refer me to an external link that explains it, but I was still confused and don't know how to implement this into my coding. This website I am developing is going to be a personal website.

Any help is appreciated. If you have to copy my code and show me that way, feel free to do so. I just want to know how to do it with my coding.

Here is my coding

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="Favicon.ico" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css" />
    <meta name="description" content="Allen Henderson's website">
    <title>HOME | Allen Henderson</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="nav-bar-container" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="200">
        <div id="logo">
            <center><img src="img/navigation-bar-header-img.jpg" /></center>
        </div>
        <ul id="nav-bar">
            <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">ENTERTAINMENT</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="main-content">     
        <h3>New Content I Have Added:</h3>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
@font-face {

    font-family: Hot Sweat;
    src: url(fonts/HotSweat.ttf);
}

@font-face {

    font-family: Rusted Orlando;
    src: url('fonts/rusted_orlando/Rusted Orlando Demo.ttf');
    src: url('fonts/rusted_orlando/Rusted Orlando Demo.otf');
}

@font-face {

    font-family: Kimberly;
    src: url(fonts/Kimberly/Kimberly.ttf);
    src: url(fonts/Kimberly/Kimberly.otf);
}


body {
    margin: 0;
}

#nav-bar-container {
    background-color: #0404B4;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;


}

#nav-bar-container.affix {

    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
}



#nav-bar {

    background-color: #0404B4;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    float: right;
}

#nav-bar li {
    display: inline;
    padding: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
}

#nav-bar li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-family: Hot Sweat;
    color: orange;
    text-align: right;
}

#main-content h1 {
    font-family: Rusted Orlando;
    color: #0404B4;
}
```

If you require additional information to answer the question, please ask and I will clarify for you.

Answer (score 0):

```js
//THE JAVASCRIPT HERE IS ONLY TO POPULATE THE PAGE, YOU CAN REMOVE IT.
var pageText = document.getElementById("text-content"); 
//create a loop of text just to populatethe page to get a y-axis overflow 
for(var i = 0; i < 100; i++){
 pageText.innerHTML += "This is the 100 line of page text "+"<br>";
}
```

```css
#logo{
   border:1px solid gray;
 width:25%;
 margin:auto;
 background-color:#ddd;
 height:100px;
}
.navbar{
 position:sticky !important;
 top:0;
 background-color:red;
 z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="Favicon.ico" />
  <meta name="description" content="Allen Henderson's website">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <title>HOME | Allen Henderson</title>
</head>
<body>

<div id="logo-banner  text-center">
 <div id="logo">
     <img src="img/navigation-bar-header-img.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="top-image"/>
 </div>
</div>


<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-primary navbar-dark">
 <ul class="navbar-nav">
    <li class="nav-item active">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Entertainment</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>


<div class="container-fluid">

<div class="row">
 <div class="col-sm-12" id="main-content">
  <h3>New Content I Have Added:</h3>
  <p id="text-content"></p>
 </div>
</div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

```js
 //NOTE:You can easily do this with jQuery, but it's good to know what's happening under the hood.
 //we'll be doing this with pure javascript.
var pageText = document.getElementById("text-content"); 

//create a loop of text just to populatethe page to get a y-axis overflow 
for(var i = 0; i < 100; i++){
 pageText.innerHTML += "This is the 100 line of page text "+"<br>";
}

//add eventlistener
//this will fire a call backfunction when you start to scroll the page
window.addEventListener("scroll", ()=>{
 var logo  = document.getElementById("logo");
 var myNav = document.getElementById("myNav");
    var logoHeight = logo.offsetHeight;//get the logo height; 
    var pageYaxis = window.pageYOffset;//get the window's y axis

    //check of we've scrolled past the image height;
    if(pageYaxis > logoHeight){
    //this will append bootstraps fixed top class to the nav element 
     myNav.classList.add("fixed-top");
    }else{
    //this will remove bootstrap fixed top class to the nav element
     myNav.classList.remove("fixed-top");
    }

})
```

```css
/*this is the only css we need*/
#logo{
 border:1px solid gray;
 width:25%;
 margin:auto;
 background-color:#ddd;
 height:100px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="Favicon.ico" />
  <meta name="description" content="Allen Henderson's website">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <title>HOME | Allen Henderson</title>
</head>
<body>

<div id="logo-banner  text-center">
 <div id="logo">
     <img src="img/navigation-bar-header-img.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="top-image"/>
 </div>
</div>


<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-primary navbar-dark"  id="myNav">
 <ul class="navbar-nav">
    <li class="nav-item active">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Entertainment</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>


<div class="container-fluid">

<div class="row">
 <div class="col-sm-12" id="main-content">
  <h3>New Content I Have Added:</h3>
  <p id="text-content"></p>
 </div>
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: How do I do it with CSS and HTML? I don't like using JavaScript.

Comment: I've edited it, on more javascript. If you're using bootstrap, make sure you set position to sticky and flag it as important, give it a higher z-Index. This will give priority to your syntax over bootstrap default.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is `position: sticky` with a setting of `top: 0`. [Take a look at this link](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_sticky_element) which walks through that bit of CSS. One other thing is just to look over your entire CSS, it's pretty messy and has a lot of conflicting CSS rules, especially when it comes to `display`.

Comment: While I do realize that I may have some conflicting CSS rules, I will be looking in to remedying said conflicts. Also, position: sticky is what I was looking for. I appreciate everyone's help!